# How can I include quotations in a CONCATENATE operation?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, concatenation

I've got an Excel file with a list of file paths that I need to perform actions on, via batch operation.  I figured the best way to do this would be to write a CONCATENATE formula to put together the command for me, copy it down all the rows, and dump the column into a batch file.

However, some of the file paths contain spaces.  For a batch command to work on these properly, I need to encase the path in quotes.  However, any time I try to put the quotes into the CONCATENATE formula, they either don't make it into the end result or the cause the formula to error out.  How can I resolve this?

For example, given:

[image]

What CONCATENATE formula would put the following into C2:

`COPY "C:\My Files\*.*" "D:\My Backup\*.*" /Y`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1:** You can use CHAR(34) to represent quotes. For your example:

```
=CONCATENATE("COPY ", CHAR(34), A2,"*.*",CHAR(34)," ",CHAR(34), B2,"*.*",CHAR(34), "/Y")
```

**Option 2:** You can also create a Name for Char(34) and use it instead of typing the formula each time you need quotes.

[image]

*Example:*

`=CONCATENATE("COPY ", quot, A2, "*.*", quot, " ", quot, B2, "*.*", quot, "/Y")`

**Option 3:** You can also enter a single quotation mark into a blank cell and just point to it in your formula.

*Example:*

`=CONCATENATE("COPY ", F1, A2, "*.*", F1, " ", F1, B2, "*.*", F1, "/Y")`

where `F1` contains `"`

Answer (score 3):

```
= "Copy """ & A1 & "*.*"" """ & B1 & "*.*"" /Y"
```