# How do I add two URLs into given format?

Tags: microsoft-excel, hyperlink

I have a excel sheet..That contains two urls sets..I need to add them into this format in another column

```
Col 1                       Col 2

Web site A.1               Web site B.1
Web site A.2               Web site B.2
```

New column should be like this..

```
<a href="web site A.1"target="_blank">web site B.1</a> 
<a href="web site A.2"target="_blank">web site B.2</a>
```

How to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I include quotations in a CONCATENATE operation?](http://superuser.com/questions/306658/how-can-i-include-quotations-in-a-concatenate-operation)

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you looking for an actual click-able hyperlink or just combined text?

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate everything all together:

In cell `C1` use the formula `="<a href=" & char(34) & A1 & char(34) & " target=" & char(34) & "_blank" & char(34) & ">" & B1 & "</a>"`